# How can I get more specific CloudWatch alerts when an AWS Lambda function fails?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a variety of functions, all in Node.js, in AWS Lambda. They're triggered by certain events like S3 triggers, API Gateway methods, or sometimes just called manually. I create them by pasting code in the console or uploading a zip file I've built locally.

On rare occasion, a function will fail. To detect failures, I've set up a CloudWatch alarm that looks like this:

[image: CloudWatch alarm]

This works, to an extent: when a function anywhere in my account fails, I get an email. The problem is the email just states that the alarm got tripped. It doesn't state *what* Lambda function actually failed so I have to dig through Lambda to find which function actually caused the alarm.

I've considered the following:

1. Setting up a CloudWatch alarm per function. This is the most obvious solution but is also the most tedious and highest maintenance.
2. Building a CI/CD pipeline for my Lambda functions instead of entering the code or uploading zips in the console. I can then add a step that sets up a CloudWatch alert for the function automatically. This is better than the first option but also is a lot of infrastructure to set up for potentially a simple problem.
3. Using another Lambda function to custom handle the alert. The problem is, best I can tell, the SNS message that CloudWatch publishes doesn't contain any more data than the email; it just says in essence "your alarm named X tripped" but not why.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi!, welcome to stack overflow, what language are you using in Lambda please?

Comment: Maybe look into a [Dead Letter Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) for your lambda. I haven't used it, but it might be something worth looking at for you.

Answer (score 0):

We handle it internally. When there is a problem, the Lambda attempts to handle it, and sends an alert. The CloudWatch metric is only for truly unhandled exceptions. Remember Lambda automatically retries if a function has an error, which can be undesirable for certain situations. So it may be preferable to handle any exceptions internal to the Lambda function.